# Do Parashara Smriti forbids marrying non-virgin girl?

Tags: marriage, smriti

Some of the smritis like Manu forbids marrying a girl who is not a virgin.

Is there such mention in Parasara smriti also?

Answer (score 5):

That's not true

From Parashara Smriti (28)

> When her husband is missing, or is dead, or has renounced the world, or is impotent, or has been degraded by sin, — on any of the said five calamities befalling a woman, law has ordained another husband for her

Src : https://archive.org/stream/ParasharaSmriti/SriParasharaSmrithiPdf_djvu.txt

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question in the title "Do Parashara Smriti forbids marrying non-virgin girl?"

Comment: @iruvar - If the text says that remarriage is possible then it means that non-virgins can get married

Comment: OK. Does it have anything to say on non-virgins that have never been married previously?

Comment: @iruvar - It cannot say otherwise the concept of kanina son would not exist